# Retrieve a cookie using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I need to get a cookie from a server using Spring RestTemplate. Do you guys know how I can perform this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
final String url = "http://codeflex.co:8080/rest/Management/login";

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
Credentials cred = new Credentials();
cred.setUserName("admin@codeflex.co");
cred.setPassword("godmode");

HttpEntity<Credentials> request = new HttpEntity<>(cred);       
HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
String set_cookie = headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
```

code from [the example](http://codeflex.co/java-rest-client-get-cookie/)

Answer (score -2):

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getValue());
HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
ResponseEntity rssResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
    "https://jira.example.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/18107/SearchRequest-18107.xml?tempMax=1000",
    HttpMethod.GET,
    requestEntity,
    Rss.class);
Rss rss = rssResponse.getBody();
```

from http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/08/sending-cookies-with-resttemplate

Comment: question asked to get cookie not set it